# Formatting CDATA string shows unexpected character

Tags: android, android-resources

I have this string entry:

```
<string name="title_label">[<![CDATA[<b>Title</b>]]> %s</string>
```

and I format it this way:

```
String titleLabel = getString(R.string.title_label);
Spanned title = Html.fromHtml(String.format(titleLabel, "My Title"));
```

However, it shows:

[**Title** My Title

instead of:

**Title** My Title

Why is it showing the '[' character in the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to :

```
<string name="title_label"><![CDATA[<b>Title</b>]]> %s</string>
```

Comment: Omg, silly me! Thanks. In 10 minutes I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, it happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you have 3 opening and 2 closing square brackets there in your XML :)

Happens to the best of us :)